# Which is the biggest set we can took off the domain of a holomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis

If a function $f$ is holomorphic on the entire $\mathbb{C}$-plane, we can took of finite points in order to remain holomorphicity on the function. Which is the largest subset of $\mathbb{C}$ we can took off from the domain of $f$ in order to preserve holomorphicity? I.e., which is the largest set where an holomorphic function need to be holomorphic in order to conclude that tooking off this set $f$ remains holomorphic?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the question correctly.  If $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, its restriction to any open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is also holomorphic...

Comment: It should follow from [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem)  that if : $U$ is an open set, $\Omega$ is open and dense in $U$, $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ and **continuous** on $U$ then $f$ is also holomorphic on $U$.

Comment: What you are looking for is possibly the concept of Removable sets. See here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_capacity